# Spring integration dsl: http outbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

Faced spring integration java-dsl issue, I'm stuck. This is a code I have for my flow declaration:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow orchestrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(queueConnectionFactory())
                        .destination(bookingQueue())
                        .outputChannel(bookingChannel()))
                .<String, BookingRequest>transform(s -> {
                    Ticket t = new Gson().fromJson(s, Ticket.class);
                    return new BookingRequest()
                            .setMovieId(t.getMovie().getId())
                            .setRow(t.getSeat().getRow())
                            .setSeat(t.getSeat().getNumber())
                            .setScreenNumber(t.getScreenNumber()
                            );
                })
                // HTTP part goes here
                .<BookingRequest, HttpEntity>transform(HttpEntity::new)
                .handle(
                        Http.outboundChannelAdapter(bookingServerUrl)
                                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                .extractPayload(true)
                                .expectedResponseType(BookStatus.class)
                )
                // and here HTTP part ends
                .handle(
                        Jms.outboundAdapter(responseDestinationTemplate())
                )
                .get();
    }
```

And everything was OK until I utilized HTTP outbound channel adapter. I need to call simple RESTful interface and code above does it pretty well. But, following `Jms.outboundAdapter(responseDestinationTemplate())` line leads to nothing, no action performes after successfull http call.

If I remove http flow part (surrounded by comments) - it works. Implemented so much stuff, almost understood and saw beauty and simplicity of integration ...aand this is it. Yet another place I got stuck in.

And here are log after success REST call:

```
2016-02-08 21:01:22.155 DEBUG 18209 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://localhost:9052/api/book" resulted in 200 (OK)
2016-02-08 21:01:22.156 DEBUG 18209 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading [class c.e.m.integration.domain.BookStatus] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6b9469bd]
2016-02-08 21:01:22.168 DEBUG 18209 --- [enerContainer-1] i.h.o.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler : handler 'org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#0' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=<BookingRequest(movieId=0, row=1, seat=1, screenNumber=1),{}>, headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_replyTo=queue://statusChannel, jms_correlationId=5021291a-d4d5-47ca-b591-b6f311378688, correlationId=1d41f05a-3695-4adb-87b0-d75c17bbc3ad, id=a1fb2a2f-5d78-3183-d409-3f60aae74a20, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1454950877264, jms_messageId=ID:ins-laptop-31198-1454948247657-1:9:1:1:1, timestamp=1454950877352}]
2016-02-08 21:01:22.168 DEBUG 18209 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inboundFlow.channel#2', message: GenericMessage [payload=<BookingRequest(movieId=0, row=1, seat=1, screenNumber=1),{}>, headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_replyTo=queue://statusChannel, jms_correlationId=5021291a-d4d5-47ca-b591-b6f311378688, correlationId=1d41f05a-3695-4adb-87b0-d75c17bbc3ad, id=a1fb2a2f-5d78-3183-d409-3f60aae74a20, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1454950877264, jms_messageId=ID:ins-laptop-31198-1454948247657-1:9:1:1:1, timestamp=1454950877352}]
2016-02-08 21:01:22.168 DEBUG 18209 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inboundFlow.channel#1', message: GenericMessage [payload=BookingRequest(movieId=0, row=1, seat=1, screenNumber=1), headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_replyTo=queue://statusChannel, jms_correlationId=5021291a-d4d5-47ca-b591-b6f311378688, correlationId=1d41f05a-3695-4adb-87b0-d75c17bbc3ad, id=859af23d-214f-4400-e9cb-7d40308755cd, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1454950877264, jms_messageId=ID:ins-laptop-31198-1454948247657-1:9:1:1:1, timestamp=1454950877350}]
2016-02-08 21:01:22.168 DEBUG 18209 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inboundFlow.channel#0', message: GenericMessage [payload={"screenNumber":1,"seat":{"row":1,"number":1},"movie":{"id":0,"name":"The Matrix"}}, headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_replyTo=queue://statusChannel, jms_correlationId=5021291a-d4d5-47ca-b591-b6f311378688, correlationId=1d41f05a-3695-4adb-87b0-d75c17bbc3ad, id=636638ed-aec2-082e-6181-0484999fd807, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1454950877264, jms_messageId=ID:ins-laptop-31198-1454948247657-1:9:1:1:1, timestamp=1454950877331}]
```

No errors, no warnings at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Integration provides two `MessageHandler` types: one-way - just handle message and stop. And another one is like: handle request message and produce reply to the output channel.

The first one is called like `outboundChannelAdapter` and with your HTTP case you just only send a POST request and don't worry about the reply.

Since the message flow is stopped on the `outboundChannelAdapter` no any further action is possible in the integration chain. Like in your case the next `Jms.outboundAdapter` won't be reached.

If you really expect the `reply` from your REST service you should use `Http.outboundGateway` instead. And your `BookStatus` will be sent to the JMS as you'd like by your last `.handle()` in the flow.

Comment: @IgorPetrov could you please post the solution ??